# How does WordPress work out the srcsets?

Tags: images

WordPress gives some images `srcset` but not others how does it work this out, I cannot find anything documenting the topic. How does WordPress decide which images to give the `srcset` attributes to.

Comment: Are you asking how the `srcset` attribute works or how WordPress decides which images to add `srcset` to and others not to?

Comment: I would like to know how it decides which images to apply the srcset on

Answer (score 0):

There could be a filter function applied that results in some images being skipped when core applies srcset. `wp_filter_content_tags()`